# how to access elements in 2d array using one dimensional array representation ? In C language

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    main()
    {
    int a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int *p;
    p=a[0];printf("\nres:%d\n",*p); //here p points to a[0][0]
    p=a[1];printf("\nres:%d\n",*p); //here p points to a[1][1]
    p=a[2];printf("\nres:%d\n",*p); //here p points to a[2][2]
    p=a[12];printf("\nres:%d\n",*p); //here p points to garbage value
    }
```

how to access or point a[0][1] and other elements using only a[i] representation,what should the value of i be ?

Comment: `p=a[0] + 1;` //p points to a[0][1]. also `p=a[1];` //p points to a[1][0], `p=a[2];` //p points to a[2][0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p=a[0];printf("\nres:%d\n",*p); //here p points to a[0][0]
```

Correct.

```
p=a[1];printf("\nres:%d\n",*p); //here p points to a[1][1]
```

Incorrect. `p` points to `a[1][0]`.

```
p=a[2];printf("\nres:%d\n",*p); //here p points to a[2][2]
```

Incorrect. `p` points to `a[2][0]`.

> how to access or point `a[0][1]`

```
p = a[0];  // p points to a[0][0]
++p;       // Now p points to a[0][1]
```

You can also use:

```
p = &a[0][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = a[i] + i;//point to a[i][i]
p = a[i]; //point to a[i][0]
```

That's how to get the element of array.